# CGI script runned with ModPerl::Registry doesn't print result on html page, just download it

Tags: mod-perl2, mod-perl-registry

Here is my sandbox https://github.com/pavelsr/mod_perl_sandbox

When I make `docker-compose up` then go to http://localhost:3000/env.pl resulted html is downloaded, not served.

Under CGI mode (with removed `-DMODPERL` in docker-compose) everything works fine.

Seems like ModPerl::Registry does not process `Content-type: text/html`

What I need to do fix in `httpd.conf` ?

Adding `PerlOptions +ParseHeaders` wil not fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. `PerlOptions +ParseHeaders` was inside `<Location` tag so was not working. To fix it you should move `ParseHeaders` to `<Directory` or set globally.

https://github.com/pavelsr/mod_perl_sandbox - work example of how to run same perl script under CGI and mod_perl